# Помогите создать метод в котором можно изменять Ui

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть cpp файл который привязан к "h" файлу и я в этом c++ файле хочу создавать свои методы которые могут поменять Ui(Допустим поменять текст в QLabel). Как это можно реализовать?

h файл

```html
#ifndef FRIENDBATTLE_H
#define FRIENDBATTLE_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class FriendBattle;
}

class FriendBattle : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Ui::FriendBattle *ui;
    explicit FriendBattle(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~FriendBattle();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_6_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_7_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_8_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_9_clicked();



private:




//    void on_pushButton_10_clicked();



};

#endif // FRIENDBATTLE_H
```

c++ file`

```html
#include "friendbattle.h"
#include "ui_friendbattle.h"
#include "iostream"

#include <QDebug>

int i = 1;
int arr[3][3];
int stepInGame = 1;

void checkWin()
{/*здесь я хочу обратиться к ui и изменить его*/}


FriendBattle::FriendBattle(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FriendBattle)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "a";

}

FriendBattle::~FriendBattle()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

`

Comment: Покажите, что у вас есть и чем возникла проблема? Карты на стол

Comment: Я внёс некие корректировки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private slots:
  void checkWin()
```

`checkWin` объявите как слот, чтоб `ui` был доступен в контексте

```
void FriendBattle::checkWin() {

  ui->label_1.setText('text')

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё получилось :). Я пытался запихнуть метод в public, а не private slots).

Comment: с паблик слотом тоже должно было получиться. у вас неймспейса не хватало `FriendBattle::`

Comment: я добавлял просто в  public, а не public slots и неймплейс я добавлял